# powershell how to resolve name to IP address using Windows method

Tags: powershell, resolve

I see people using this:

```
[Net.DNS]::GetHostEntry("serverName").addressList[0].IPAddressToString
```

...and that will work for me. Except, what if I have an entry in the hosts file? Does this use the same method that Windows uses or skip the DNS cache and hosts file and always query a DNS server? I would like to use whatever method Windows uses for browers, Windows Explorer, ping, etc.

Comment: So what happens if you add a dummy entry for, say, `google.com` to your hosts file and the run `[Net.DNS]::GetHostEntry("google.com").addressList[0].IPAddressToString`?

Comment: Why not give it a try and see what happens? (It will be faster than waiting for someone else to test it for you and write a response.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not just use the built-in DNS cmdlets? 
Or is there a particular reason you are traveling down the raw .Net path?
Code project, homework assignment, curiosity?

```
 Get-Command -Name Resolve-Dns* | Format-Table -AutoSize

CommandType Name                   Version Source       
----------- ----                   ------- ------       
Cmdlet      Resolve-DnsName        1.0.0.0 DnsClient     



# Get parameters, examples, full and Online help for a cmdlet or function

(Get-Command -Name Resolve-DnsName).Parameters
Get-help -Name Resolve-DnsName -Examples
Get-help -Name Resolve-DnsName -Full
Get-help -Name Resolve-DnsName -Online


Resolve-DnsName -Name stackoverflow.com -Type A | Format-Table -AutoSize

Name              Type TTL Section IPAddress     
----              ---- --- ------- ---------     
stackoverflow.com A    268 Answer  151.101.65.69 
stackoverflow.com A    268 Answer  151.101.193.69
stackoverflow.com A    268 Answer  151.101.129.69
stackoverflow.com A    268 Answer  151.101.1.69  



Get-Content C:\WINDOWS\System32\Drivers\Etc\hosts

# Copyright (c) 1993-2009 Microsoft Corp.
#
# This is a sample HOSTS file used by Microsoft TCP/IP for Windows.
#
# This file contains the mappings of IP addresses to host names. Each
# entry should be kept on an individual line. The IP address should
# be placed in the first column followed by the corresponding host name.
# The IP address and the host name should be separated by at least one
# space.
#
# Additionally, comments (such as these) may be inserted on individual
# lines or following the machine name denoted by a '#' symbol.
#
# For example:
#
#      102.54.94.97     rhino.acme.com          # source server
#       38.25.63.10     x.acme.com              # x client host

# localhost name resolution is handled within DNS itself.
#   127.0.0.1       localhost
#   ::1             localhost


Resolve-DnsName -Name localhost -Type ANY | Format-Table -AutoSize


Name              Type TTL  Section IPAddress
----              ---- ---  ------- ---------
localhost.lab.net A    1260 Answer  127.0.0.1



Resolve-DnsName -Name $env:COMPUTERNAME -Type ANY | Format-Table -AutoSize

Name Type TTL Section IPAddress                             
---- ---- --- ------- ---------                             
WS01 A    30  Answer  10....                            
WS01 AAAA 30  Answer  2601:...             
WS01 AAAA 30  Answer  2601:...
WS01 AAAA 30  Answer  fe80::...
```

Using the raw .Net call, will give you ...

```
[Net.DNS]::GetHostEntry('stackoverflow.com').addressList[0].IPAddressToString
151.101.65.69

[Net.DNS]::GetHostEntry('localhost').addressList[0].IPAddressToString
::1

[Net.DNS]::GetHostEntry($env:COMPUTERNAME).addressList[0].IPAddressToString
fe80::...
```

Comment: I wasn't thinking clearly. I should have done more testing myself. And using the .Net commands usually gives more options that are sometimes more precisely what I need, plus there's more likely to be a method I can use that is more likely to be found with a Google search and more likely to be available on more servers regardless of operating system version. And, once I know the command, it's not really any more difficult to use than a cmdlet. Thanks.

Comment: for powershell, what's the distinction between a `cmdlet` and `.NET` command?

Comment: This is giving me unknown host when i try getting hostname for IP Address...