# Exception calling "GetHostEntry" with "1" argument(s): "No such device or address"

Tags: linux, powershell, scripting, system-administration, fqdn

The `FQDN` for this machine:

```
thufir@dur:~$ 
thufir@dur:~$ hostname --fqdn
dur.bounceme.net
thufir@dur:~$
```

Yes...working [directly](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48807254/262852) with `powershell` gives the `FQDN` of `dur.bounceme.net` okay:

```
thufir@dur:~/powershell$ 
thufir@dur:~/powershell$ pwsh
PowerShell v6.0.1
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

https://aka.ms/pscore6-docs
Type 'help' to get help.

PS /home/thufir/powershell> 
PS /home/thufir/powershell> [System.Net.Dns]::GetHostByName((hostname)).HostName                                        
dur.bounceme.net
PS /home/thufir/powershell>
```

but what if I want to iterate over an array?  How do I get the `FQDN` to show as `dur.bounceme.net`?

```
thufir@dur:~/powershell$ 
thufir@dur:~/powershell$ ./hostname.ps1 
dur.bounceme.net
beginning loop
google.com
Exception calling "GetHostEntry" with "1" argument(s): "No such device or address"
At /home/thufir/powershell/hostname.ps1:14 char:3
+   $fqdn = [System.Net.Dns]::GetHostEntry($i).HostName
+   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : ExtendedSocketException

google.com
localhost
end
thufir@dur:~/powershell$
```

script:

```
#!/usr/bin/pwsh -Command


#hostname is a reserved variable name?

[System.Net.Dns]::GetHostByName((hostname)).HostName


"beginning loop"

$hosts = ("google.com", "hostname", "localhost")

foreach($i in $hosts) {
  $fqdn = [System.Net.Dns]::GetHostEntry($i).HostName
  write-host $fqdn
}


"end"
```

I've tried removing quote marks from around `hostname` and prepending the dollar sign `$`.  This is a reserved word?

Bonus points for explaining the terminology involved.

Comment: What result do you expect to get about _hostname_?

Comment: @vonPryz dur.bounceme.net is the FQDN.  I updated the question a bit.  How do I get the FQDN output from powershell as a script?  Please elaborate -- not sure what you're getting at.

Comment: I'm probably nitpicking, but *`dur.bounceme.net`* is ***not*** a FQDN. FQDN's end in dot like *`dur.bounceme.net.`*.The dot indicates the top of the DNS tree. Your hostname allows search domains to be appended, like *`dur.bounceme.net.example.com`*. Also see [Fully Qualified Domain Name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fully_qualified_domain_name) on Wikipedia; or W. Richard Stevens' [TCP/IP Illustrated](https://www.amazon.com/dp/0201633469) for the win!

Comment: @jww err, are you saying that `google.com` isn't a FQDN but that `google.com.` is?

Comment: @Thufir - yes, exactly. But also see issues like [hostnamed does not like fqdns with trailing dots](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/6369). Systemd has the resolver screwed up. I don't think Poettering understands what a FQDN means and how he changed the behaviors. I've been waiting for a security vulnerability to surface because of it.

Answer (score 1):

You are using hostname as a string and that string is not in your hosts file, like localhost is, it will fail.

If you are after default localhost names, then they are:

```
'127.0.0.1'
$env:COMPUTERNAME
'localhost'
```

So, you shoud do this

```
$TargetHosts = ('stackoverflow.com','google.com', $env:COMPUTERNAME,'localhost','127.0.0.1')

foreach($TargetHost in $TargetHosts) 
{ ( $fqdn = [Net.Dns]::GetHostEntry($TargetHost).Hostname ) }

stackoverflow.com
google.com
WS01
WS01
WS01
```

See also this post about use the native Resolve-DnsName cmdlet vs the .NET libraries.

> Why not just use the built-in DNS cmdlets? Or is there a particular
>   reason you are traveling down the raw .Net path? Code project,
>   homework assignment, curiosity?
>
> [powershell how to resolve name to IP address using Windows method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48778955/powershell-how-to-resolve-name-to-ip-address-using-windows-method/48779840?noredirect=1#comment84604440_48779840)

Comment: curiosity.  this script generates an error for the $env:COMPUTERNAME for me -- probably because it's Linux and not windows (?).  I'll update the question.  thx.

Comment: Correct, $env:COMPUTERNAME is a Windows PoSH default variable from the $env:\ PSDrive. On OSX/*NIX, in PS terminal, that is not a thing. The iteration of what I show does work on OSX/*NIX, as long as you do not use the $env:COMPUTERNAME or hostname. hostname on OSX, does return the local computer name, it does not when doing what is being tried here. So for OSX/*NIX hosts, you are left with localhost and 127.0.0.1. I just did all this in OSX to validate.

Comment: maybe going off track here.  The OS command `hostname --fqdn` returns a string.  Can that output not be passed or piped to `GetHostByName`?  Along with other arbitrary strings in an array.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that there is confusion about what *hostname* does and what's the difference between a command and a string. Let's see the first part that works:

```
[System.Net.Dns]::GetHostByName((hostname)).HostName
```

Powershell parses this as

```
Run command hostname, 
Call GetHostByName(), pass hostname's output as a parameter to the call
from that result, show the HostName attribute
```

Whilst in the foreach loop, the parameters are passed as *strings*. Thus in the *hostname* case:

```
$i <-- hostname
[System.Net.Dns]::GetHostEntry($i).HostName
```

is being parsed as

```
Call GetHostEntry("hostname")
from that result, show the HostName attribute
```

Comment: so when PS runs the command hostname this returns an object?  That object is a parameter for the call to GetHostByName?  If so, then:  how do I get the object returned by the command `hostname`?

Comment: @Thufir Yes, running the _command_ hostname will return a string object that contains your _computer's_ hostname. (Maybe it doesn't help that the word _hostname_ is a [homonym](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homonym).) When you pass a list of strings, there is no way to know that one is supposed to be name for executable to be called and others are just strings.

Comment: Stuck on *command* meaning. You mean the OS command on the console?  Just `hostname` on the OS.